# Design Configuration menu in custom phtml file

Tags: magento, layout, admin, adminhtml

I want to design a custom menu just like the admin configuration menu in magento as you can see in the image below.

[image: admin menu]

I have a custom phtml file and I want the same menu in that file. how can I do this using built-in magento functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is great manual from Alan Storm, how to create custom tabs in admin panel

http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration